# Is there a sequence of these numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been studying number theory recently. I started thinking about a certain number which has peculiar properties and I wondered whether there was a sequence for such numbers somewhere, for example in OEIS. I have gone through OEIS but couldn't find it. The number is as follows

Take a number n where n is an integer. $s(n)$ is the aliquot sum of n. $D(n)$ is the deficiency of n.

Is there a number n such that $\frac{s(n)}{D(n)}=r$ where r is some integer.

In other words, is there a number n whose deficiency divides its aliquot sum? If these numbers exist, is there an OEIS list for its sequence? Kindly avoid the trivial case where deficiency is 1.

Let me give more details about these functions.  $\sigma (n)=n+s(n)$. and $D(n)+s(n)=n$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142542/discussion-on-question-by-user2346876-is-there-a-sequence-of-these-numbers); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: There is an elephant in the room, its name is [A060326](https://oeis.org/A060326), and it looks remarkably similar to the one that escaped from your zoo yesterday.

Comment: @IvanNeretin indeed it is the same sequence. Thank you for finding it. But there are still a lot of unknown properties regarding the sequence.

Comment: A271816 is the sequence that includes powers of two as well.  There are several references there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since our productive discussion has been deleted, I bring this back as an answer.
Peter calculated a list of $n$ that work.  I noted it includes numbers of the form
$$n=2^{p-1}(2^p+2^q-1)$$
for $q\lt p$ when $2^p+2^q-1$ is prime.
There are other solutions not of that form, the first one is $n=884$.