# Are all elements in this sequence even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a continuation of an earlier enquiry about a peculiar sequence that I have been studying. The earlier question can be found here [Is there a sequence of these numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629644/is-there-a-sequence-of-these-numbers?noredirect=1#comment9766940_4629644)

The integer in question is described below.
Take a number n where n is an integer. $s(n)$ is the aliquot sum of n. $D(n)$ is the deficiency of n.

Is there a number n such that $\frac{s(n)}{D(n)}=r$ where r is some integer.

In other words, is there a number n whose deficiency divides its aliquot sum? If these numbers exist, is there an OEIS list for its sequence? Kindly avoid the trivial case where deficiency is 1.

Let me give more details about these functions.  $\sigma (n)=n+s(n)$. and $D(n)+s(n)=n$

In that previous question, a user by the name Peter found a sequence of such numbers. However, we noticed that all of these numbers were even numbers. It begs the question, are all numbers in this peculiar sequence even?

The sequence of the first 21 of these numbers is given below.
10, 44, 136, 152, 184, 752, 884, 2144, 2272, 2528, 8384, 12224, 17176, 18632, 18904, 32896, 33664, 34688, 49024, 63248, 85936

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $\sigma(n)$ must be odd too.  It is known that $n$ is therefore a square number.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08994 may be helpful -- $r$ relates to the "Abundancy outlaws" discussed there.

Comment: Thank you  Empy2 and  Alex K for the information. Let me do further research on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upto $10^9$ , there are two solutions not divisible by $4$ , namely $10$ and $9018009$

So, there is at least one odd such number.

Comment: With the above useful restriction , we can extend the search limit for odd cases drastically. It turns out that there is no other example upto $10^{16}$

Comment: Thanks Peter. Are your calculations using a lot of computer processing power and time? How feasible would it be to increase that range to say $10^{100}$? Also are you still using the same code as the one you posted yesterday? In particular, have you added something in your code that counts the number of odd numbers in the sequence? If so, could you post the new code that has this restriction?

Comment: $10^{100}$ is only feasible, if we detect some further particular structure. For the odd cases , we only need to check the squares (see above comment) , so we can set $n=m^2$ and let $m$ run to $10^8$ to complete the range upto $10^{16}$. But this cannot (yet) be done for even numbers. Maybe someone finds more necessary conditions.

Comment: I found many solutions with $2^k\cdot m$ ($m>1$ odd) with larger $k$ , but none yet with $k=16$.

Comment: There is no such number of the form $2^{16}\cdot m$ with $m$ odd and $3\le m\le 10^9$

Comment: Dear Peter this is an interesting result. It is also very strange how there is only one odd number in the sequence upto 10^16. Very strange indeed.

Comment: If there is an odd positive integer $m\ne 3\ 003$ such that $m^2$ is a solution , $m$ must exceed $4\cdot 10^9$. I found some reasons why odd numbers are so unlikely to be a solution, but some surprise remains that it seems to be only one.

Comment: Thank you Peter. If you don't mind, could you kindly share with us the reason why odd numbers are unlikely to be a solution?  Also I found this paper on Arxiv that is somehow related to this problem.  I am sure that Theorem 1.1 will be of interest to you since it talks about this strange number $3,003^2$ whose prime factorisation is $3^27^211^213^2$ The paper says that this number is the only odd solution with four distinct prime divisors. https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04932

Comment: We have to solve $$(2k-1)\cdot s^2=\sigma(s^2)\cdot k$$ with odd numbers $k,s>1$. If $k$ is large , we must have $\frac{\sigma(s^2)}{s^2}\approx 2$ (It must always be smaller than $2$). The larger $k$ , the nearer must the fraction be at $2$. On the other hand, if $p$ is a prime factor of $s$ , but not of $k$ , then we must have $p^2\mid \sigma(s^2)$.

Comment: @User2346876 Does the paper establish other conditions ? For example, that $s$ must be squarefree or must have at least three prime factors or something like that ?

Comment: @User2346876 I found a solution for exponent $16$ in the linked question , maybe it is of interest for you.

Comment: Peter, to the best of my knowledge I have not yet seen anyone describe the properties of s. I don't remember seeing this equation in the literature so far, it could be a new contribution to the field. That paper only proves that there is only 1 odd deficient perfect number with 4 distinct prime divisors. I will go ahead and attach a second paper that proves that there are no odd deficient perfect numbers with three distinct prime divisors https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-deficientperfect-numbers/146C6AF556E1D0D593F8FBDC786B9F00

Comment: Also yes I am interested in the solution for exponent 16 in the linked question. You can go ahead and post it in the linked question.

Comment: @User2346876 I made progress in the question whether there is an example $2^k\cdot m$ with odd $m$ for every non-negative integer $k$. The smallest unknown cases are now $k=164,172,192,200$ (See also the linkes question)

Comment: Peter thank you. That is good progress. I also found out that the number $3^2.7^2.11^2.13^2$ is very famous in odd perfect number research. I was not aware of this. Apparently it appears as a factor in Descartes's spoof. See this Dris post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922297/does-k-9018009-have-a-friend

Comment: @User2346876 I am also very interested in whether the only solution of the form $4k+2$ is $10$ , which seems to be the case. Or even : Are there only finite many solutions of the form $2^k\cdot m$ with odd $m$ , if a positive integer $k$ is given ?