# Is there an example for every given exponent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629691/82961) question , where it is asked for positive integers with the property $$2n-\sigma(n)\mid \sigma(n)-n$$ which is equivalent to $$2n-\sigma(n)\mid n$$ The author also demands $2n-\sigma(n)>1$. $\sigma(n)$ is the divisor-sum function.

> Question : Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers with the above property. Is it true, that for every non-negative integer $k$ , there is a number $n=2^k\cdot m$ with some odd integer $m>1$ , such that $n\in S$ , in other words is there a solution whatever $k$ is ?

I used the following PARI/GP program to find the smallest solution, if it does not exceed $10^7$

```
check(n)={h=0;s=sigma(n);if(2*n>s+1,if(Mod(n,2*n-s)==0,h=1));h}
gp > for(k=0,23,m=3;while((m<10^7)*(check(2^k*m)==0),m=m+2);if(check(2^k*m)==1,print(k,"  ",m));if(check(2^k*m)==0,print(k,"  ?")))
0  9018009
1  5
2  11
3  17
4  47
5  67
6  131
7  257
8  1051159
9  1031
10  2063
11  4099
12  8447
13  16447
14  32771
15  65537
16  ?
17  262147
18  524351
19  1048583
20  2101247
21  4194319
22  8388623
23  ?
```

As one can see, for $k=16$ and for $k=23$ , there is no solution below $10^7$.

In the special case that $m$ is a prime number , we have
$$\sigma(n)=(2^{k+1}-1)\cdot (m+1)$$ hence $$2n-\sigma(n)=m+1-2^{k+1}$$ If this is $2^s$ with some positive integer $s\le k$, then we have found a solution with $m:=2^{k+1}+2^s-1$

This gives solutions for example for $k=23$ and $k=25$ , but not for $k=16$ and $k=24$.

Update : The smallest cases without a known example are now $$k=164,172,192,200$$

Comment: I really do not understand why someone downvoted this.

Comment: An exmple for $k=16$ : $$n=9199850692739072=2^{16}\cdot 152\ 959\cdot 917\ 753$$

Comment: An example for $k=24$ : $$n=944867948311429894897664=2^{24}\cdot  34253503\cdot  1644168143$$